# Debugging in Eclipse with real Android phone on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb, ubuntu-10.10

I can't get adb to recognising my HTC Desire on my new upgrade of Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat.

adb devices shows

```
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

Now, there are plenty of tutorials for changing rule files under /etc/udev/rules.d/.
However, I cannot find one specific for 10.10.

Can anyone tell me whether the rule file name and content is the same as described at [link text](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=823956), or are we looking at some new settings for this new release?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I guess the tutorials work, I created both 70-android.rules and 51-android.rules, re-typed them again (get rid of the funny quotes when you copy from the web).

Restart

And now it is recognised!

Comment: I kill and restart the adb server as sudo (made a shell skript for that)... works like charme, too :)

Comment: **important note:** the adb daemon must be run under "root" to have access to the usb device.

Answer (score 7):

On Linux Mint/Ubuntu 11.04 with a Samsung Galaxy S2, I didn't use any rules, but when "reset adb" or when "Devices view" it shows:

> ????????????    no permissions

I had to :

```
sudo killall adb # if I don't, I get "error: insufficient permissions for device"
sudo ./adb usb
```

Then I was able to take screenshots following this tutorials: http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-take-screenshots-of-android-device/

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

My magic spell for Ubuntu 11.04:

```
$killall adb
$sudo adb usb
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
restarting in USB mode
```

Then go to eclipse and start debugging on real device

Answer (score 2):

Ok I am a little late to the party but here is another approach...

Create a file called 51-android.rules in /etc/udev/rules.d with the following contents

> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="**04e8**", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

Then run the following command to reload the udev rules ...

`udevadm control --reload-rules`

Now plug in your galaxy S2 mobile phone into the computer's USB port and run `adb devices`.

NOTE: You will need to change the vendor id (highlighted in bold) to match your phone's vendor id (in the OP's case it should be 0bb4 for HTC)

Answer (score 0):

On windows, I had to download a Special App from HTC in order to get the proper USB drivers to connect to my Evo.  The app in question allows you to synch your outlook contacts/calendar (weee...) with those on your phone.  I rather doubt there's something similar available for ubuntu/Linux.

I strongly suspect you're up against a similar situation.  The standard USB drivers don't work with HTC phones, so you need Something Else.

If this is something that stopped working with the upgrade, you'll need to take a close look at any USB-related changes.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I know window works like magic, but it is a ubuntu specific question.

Comment: Thus the secend and third paragraphs.  Irecommend calling HTC support and seeing what the have to say.

Answer (score -1):

Hi all  i am very frustrated by checking all sides
But one day i got the solution of this problem pls follow the following steps

```
First open your device terminal
1)on the top left hand corner in Application ->Accessories->terminal
2) on terminal window type following commands
   $ sudo su then press enter after that terminal want password which is set by you  
   in    installation or giving at the time of logging.
   $<Enter password> password is not shown but it is type internally you can just type 
    whole password 
   $ mkdir ~/.android
   $vi ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
   press ctri+z here
   $ echo "0x0451" > ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
   $cat /root/.android/adb_usb.ini
    $sudo mount -t usbfs none /proc/bus/usb
   $cd path of android sdk tools from home
     like /home/tv-014/Desktop/newandroid/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
   in my system i have put android-sdk-linux at desktop and in it one platform-tools 
   folder contain the adb.exe file
   so after cd command we have the path from home to platform-tools folder.
    $ ./adb kill-server
    $ ./adb start-server
    $ ./adb devices
```

Now you got the list of devices attach to your systems.